# HELM template --set a inline key's value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

```
config:
    temp.yaml: |-
      instances:
        - server: <The value that is going to be passed from helm template --set>
          port: 443
```

command: --set config."temp\.yaml.instances[0].server"=server_url

I have a helm template like in the above example. As it can be seen temp.yaml is inline but I need to set a value thats in the inline part. Is this somehow possible to do this using only "helm template --set" command?

Answer (score 2):

`|` declare multi-line **strings**, You cloud not treat `string` like `struct`.

[helm yaml doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/yaml_techniques/#strings-in-yaml)

In addition, `--set` is used to overridden value in `values.yaml`. And the key of the value in `values.yaml` cannot contain `.`, so there cannot contain keys such as `temp.yaml`

[helm --set](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/)

One possible implementation
values.yaml

```yaml
config:
  temp: |-
    instances:
      - server: 127.0.0.1
        port: 443
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  temp.yaml: |-
  {{ $.Values.config.temp }}
```

cmd:

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  temp.yaml: |-
  instances:
  - server: 127.0.0.1
    port: 443
```

cmd 2:

```bash
helm --debug template test . --set config2.temp=\
'  instances:
     - server: 1.2.3.4
       port: 443'
```

output 2：

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  temp.yaml: |-
    instances:
     - server: 1.2.3.4
       port: 443
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only `helm install --set` (or `--set-string`) an entire string value; you can't selectively replace things inside a string or tell Helm that a string value is actually YAML.

It looks like you're trying to expose an entire ConfigMap data structure as configurable settings.  You might be able to restructure your application so most of the ConfigMap is generated in Helm template code, and only the things that need to be configured are exposed as Helm values.  For example, if your ConfigMap looks like

```yaml
# templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
  labels:
{{ include "mychart.labels" . | indent 4 }}
data:
  temp.yaml: |-
    instances:
{{ .Values.instances | toYaml | indent 6 }}
```

Now your `values.yaml` file contains the "instances" data as a YAML structure, not a string

```yaml
# values.yaml, or some `helm install -f` file
instances:
  - server: 127.0.0.1
    port: 443
```

and the `... | toYaml | indent` sequence will convert that structure back to YAML text and indent it appropriately for the ConfigMap output.

If you do this then you can use `helm install --set` in pretty much exactly the way you describe initially.